# Android : Update on UI Thread very fast

Tags: multithreading, android-imageview, android

I have an application that plays back video frame by frame. This is all working. However it needs to have playback Audio too, when Audio and Video running simultaneously it seems, Video lagging behind audio,
 Logic i am using to display the video frame as follows

```
 ProcessVideoThread(){

  // Read the data from socket, 

  // decode it : this is going to be in side libvpx library, after decoding i am getting raw     
  // bitmap data 

  // After getting raw bitmap data, use some mechanism to update the image, 
  // here i tried runOnUIThread, handler but 


 }
```

Now what is happening, it seems UI thread is getting very late chance to update the image, i.e. libvpx is taking approx 30 ms to decode the image and through runOnUIThread, its taking 40 more ms to update the image, but inside UI thread i am updating it.
Can anyone advise me, how can i reduce the delay to update the image on the UI thread.

Comment: Seems like the most expensive task is the retrieval from socket. I'd do custom painting on a Canvas-like view. Posting new Runnable objects to the event queue for each loop is too slow.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363770/813951

Comment: @MisterSmith, Thanks a lot, do you mean, from the VideoThread, i should use canvas like view, and which will avoid calling UI Thread

Comment: Exactly. Calling `runOnUiThread` involves creating a new Runnable instance, and, most important, if the calling thread is not the UI thread, enqueue the Runnable in the event queue. Thus, there's no guarantee on when the posted runnable will run. And the execution can be delayed if there are other pending UI events (menu touch events, for instance). Get rid of that and use custom drawing.

Comment: @MisterSmith, thanks for your valuable comment, i shall try that out.

Comment: Hey, Is the problem solved, Else i will try to help you..

Comment: @happy2Help, thanks its so nice of you, i am still trying to working on the canvas, its working, so far.. again i will post it if i reach to some conclusion

Comment: Fine. I happened to work on similar kind of a project on android that records and plays videos from the USB Camera. Even i used Canvas for showing the data on the screen. You can implement frequency scaling to Video frames in order to match the speed with Audio. But Yes, quality will be at stake. If you inetend to know the solution let me know, I shall post the same..

Comment: @happy2Help, In my application Audio & Video coming from different socket, only problem what i am facing is, Audio & Video is not getting sync, Video is delay or sometime audio is getting delay, some thread priority , thread synchronization is missing it seems, Audio is flowing @ 20ms i.e. 320 bytes and video is flowing @ 24fps using libvpx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks interesting. If i was in your situation, i would examine the following methods.

1) Try using Synchronization between Audio An Video Threads.

2) Try reducing the Video Frames where audio is lagging and reduce the audio frequency where Video is lagging.

You can do the same in the following way.

```
int i;
if(i%2==0)
ShowFrame();
else
i++
```

What this will do is that it will straight away reduce the Video Speed from 24 12. So the Audio will now match with video. But yaa quality will be at stake as i already mentioned to you. This method is called frequency scaling. Widely used method to sync audio and Video.

Refer to the following for clear understanding and ways in which you can sync audio and video. This is in relation to the FFMPEG. I dont know how much of it you will be able to use, but definitely it will help you to get some idea.

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html

All the Best..

Comment: As its mentioned, audio is coming @ 20ms and Video is coming @ 40ms, how it could be synchronization, what i am trying is making sure, both thread should get equal priority , as soon as we got data, try to play it ( be it audio or video ) asap, now what is happening is either of thread is getting less chance hence video is getting delayed.